# QuickBooks - QODBC Driver, Look up Item Serial Numbers

Tags: quickbooks, qodbc

I know this may be a stretch, but does anyone know where to look in the QuickBooks tables for an inventory item's serial numbers?

I have looked through all documentation I can find and can not seem to find the table that holds the serial numbers.  Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Additionally, any information on where/how to pull an items Average Cost would be awesome too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additionally, you can refer [QODBC-Desktop knowledge base - Where Item Serial Numbers or Lot Numbers are stored](http://qodbc.com/links/2976)

or

you may visit  [QODBC Table Schema](http://doc.qodbc.com/qodbc/usa/) and click "ALPHABETICAL LISTING OF ALL TABLE'S DETAIL", this will list out all the tables and fields, Just search for "SerialNumber"

Answer (score 2):

SerialNumber is only available in the ItemFixedAsset table.
AverageCost is available on the ItemInventory and ItemInventoryAssembly tables.

Here is some useful documentation for the SDK that may still help you.  [Intuit On Screen Reference](https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/common/newosr/index.html)  And here is a reference for the [QODBC Table Schema](http://doc.qodbc.com/qodbc/usa/TableList.php?categoryName=).  Using these two references I found...

The OSR ItemQuery Response shows all the different item types and their fields but the data in QODBC is broken out by item type.  I found the fields here and confirmed they are on the individual Item- tables in QODBC.

Hope this helps for this and future research.